# Spring Boot doesn't use datasource properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, database-connection, spring-jdbc, properties-file

I've set up spring.datasource.* in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./data/test
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

Then I configured JdbcTemplate Bean

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

But when I start application, I see in console

```
Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
```

Instead of my settings. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's always a magic.

When the problem occured I have had these dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

But when I changed it into

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The problem gone...

Comment: adding depedency : <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency> worked for me so spring-boot-starter-data-jpa wasn't enough

Answer (score 2):

**Solution to your question**

1. SpringBoot will always look for embedded datasource only, Check whether you have any other driver's like derby driver in your WEB-INF/lib path.
2. You exclude the datasource configuration and use importResource annotation to inject your dataSource configuration.
3. Sample Snippet below.

   ```
   @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
    @ImportResource({ "classpath:datasource-config.xml"})
     public class Sample {
   ```
4. In datasource-config.xml you can use your datasource properties file as well.
5. Enjoy :-)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I am writing desckop application, so I haven't a WEB-INF directory. I also haven't datasouce-config.xml, because a saw multiple examples without it. Anyway, I've found a solution a munite ago, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I hope it helps you.

The problem seems to be:

When you login into H2 console, it writes metadata in your user folder (.h2.server.properties). This file just configures what will appear in the console UI.

Pay close attention to the URL you put in the `JDBC URL` field of the console UI. It must match with the URL you define in the `spring.datasource.url` of the `application.properties` file.

The trick is: when running just an example application, it DO NOT create a data file until you connect/commit something into the database. So, you think the `autoconfigure feature` is not doing the job.
But when you first modify the database state, H2 creates the data file `something.mv.db` in the right folder.

Assuming you just created a new application with the following dependencies (i.e. `JDBC`,`H2` and `web`), try the following to see my point:

1) set up your pom.xml (it is the default for these three dependencies I mentioned):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

2) in the application.properties file:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./data/test
```

3) Open a file explorer window to show the contents of the root folder of your project (the same folder of your `pom.xml`).

4) Then, go to `<server>:8080/h2-console`.
In the `JDBC URL` field of the console UI, type: `jdbc:h2:file:./data/test`
and connect.

5) You will see the 'data' folder being created and inside it, the data file `test.mv.db` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inject `JdbcTemplate` in your controller class,

```
private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
public MyController(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}
```

In this way you can autowire `jdbcTemplate` in any spring bean.

Add spring boot jdbc dependency in your `pom.xml`

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

See this [spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html) for more information.

Comment: my question was about why the used url was `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false` instead of `jdbc:h2:./data/test` which I specified in `application.properties`. I am sorry if my question was unclear.

Comment: as the second part of your answer was added in 2 minutes after my answer, I'll accept my own answer.